# Executing a javascript function at the end of an SWF animation using AS3 or JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash, animation

I've been searching for an answer to my question for a while now, I made a flash animation. And I'm trying to launch a function at it's end. 
I've tried to do it directly in Flash, I don't know if I've done it correctly. 
My code :

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    flashMovie = $('#wrapanim .movie');
    flashMovie.flash({
        swf: 'RechercheYT.swf',
        width: 1000,
        height: 650,
        play: true,
    });
$("#skipA").click(function() {
        enter();
    });

});
function enter()
{
$("#wrapanim").fadeOut(200); 
.....
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapanim">
        <div id="skipA" class="skip">
            X
        </div>

        <div class="movie"></div>
    </div>
```

For the AS3 solution : On the last key frame I put this code :

> ```
> import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
> ExternalInterface.call("enter()");
> ```
>
> It didn't worked. The last clip of my animation kept running indefinitely.

I used to use first-hand a setTimeout() to launch the enter() function but I didn't liked this solution and it might cause some problems, the animation could be cut before it's end.

Well to make it simple, I'm searching a way to execute a javascript function at the end of my SWF file.

Thanks for whoever will take the time to answer and help me.

> EDITS :

Thanks for your answer, I tried what you wrote, but still it didn't work. I even tried many ways of embed my SWF, still the same problem.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="RechercheYT.swf" 
style="width:1000px;height:650px;">

<param name="movie" value="RechercheYT.swf" />
<param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />

</object>
```

On my animation :

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.call("enter");
```

(Brackets or not, I had the same issues) With every code I tried, it's always the same problem, the animation is perfectly displayed but the last movie clip and only the last movie clip keep turning non-stop. So I'm starting to think that it's coming from the animation and maybe not the code and if that's the case I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is likely because of the brackets on your ExternalInface call:

```
ExternalInterface.call("enter()");
```

Use this instead:

```
ExternalInterface.call("enter");
```

Also, make sure you're allowing script access in the swf embed code:

```
<param name='AllowScriptAccess' value='always'/>
```

Comment: Perhaps then you could post your .fla and a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I don't understand why it worked out all of sudden ^^ Have a nice day